# Android - Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-listview

I do not know what happened, there is no error in my code, but the ListView in my application can not be displayed, if there are less than my code? This my project, ListView can't displayed.

[image]
[image]

### JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is;
    String json;

    JSONObject object;

    public JSONObject getObject(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> value)  throws IOException {

        if(method == "POST"){
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();   
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else if(method == "GET"){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String param = URLEncodedUtils.format(value, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + param;
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(get);
            is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            object = null;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }

}
```

### AmbilData.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    private JSONParser jsonparser;
    ArrayList<String> d;
    JsonObjectResult jobres;
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public void init(Context c, JsonObjectResult jres, String kategori,
            String url) {
        this.context = c;
        this.jobres = jres;

        AmbilData ad = this;
        ad.execute(url, kategori, "");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Retrieve Data", "aaa");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... parameter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject jsobj = null;
        String url = (String) parameter[0];
        String kat = (String) parameter[1];
        Log.i("url", url);
        Log.i("kat", kat);
        jsonparser = new JSONParser();
        List<NameValuePair> datajson = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        datajson.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kategori", kat));
        try {
            jsobj = jsonparser.getObject(url, "POST", datajson);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsobj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            JSONObject js = (JSONObject) result;
            jobres.gotJsonObject(js);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class JsonObjectResult {
        public abstract void gotJsonObject(JSONObject jobject);
    }

}
```

Please help me ...

Comment: you are trying to parse XML as JSON.

Comment: Are you having JSON array in response or XML in response?

Comment: so what should i do? you have solutions based my code? @panini

Comment: I've updated my post, please help @Shink

Comment: Can you print the **result** object in **postexecute()** method & show us?

Comment: I hope it's the format error, you have to convert your response from server in JSON format.